# Solution verification of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{(n+r)^p}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I need to find the sum for any $p \in \mathbb{R}$, $$S=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{(n+r)^p}$$

---

**My attempt:** I will use the idea that $\lim\limits_{n \to ∞} f \cdot g = \lim\limits_{n \to ∞} f \cdot \lim\limits_{n \to ∞} g$ if and only if $f\cdot g$ is not an indeterminate form as $n \to ∞$,
$$S= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{n^p(1+r/n)^p}= \lim\limits_{n \to ∞} \dfrac{1}{n^{p-1}} \cdot \dfrac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{\left(1+r/n\right)^p}=\lim\limits_{n \to ∞} \dfrac{1}{n^{p-1}} \cdot \lim\limits_{n \to ∞} \dfrac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{\left(1+r/n\right)^p}= \lim\limits_{n \to ∞} \dfrac{1}{n^{p-1}} \int_{1}^{2} \dfrac{1}{x^p} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

---

If $p≠1$ then, $$S= \lim\limits_{n \to ∞} \dfrac{1}{n^{p-1}} \left[\left(\dfrac{2^{-p+1}}{-p+1}\right)-\left(\dfrac{1^{-p+1}}{-p+1}\right) \right]$$

If $p=1$ then, $$S= \lim \limits_{n\to ∞} \dfrac{1}{n^{1-1}} \cdot \ln 2$$

---

**Conclusion:** If $p>1$ then $S=0$, if $p=1$ then $S= \ln 2$ and if $p<1$ then $S = +\infty$

Is the reasoning correct at each and every step? Secondly, are there any alternative methods to do this? I couldn't find this question on the site.

Comment: I don't understand, when $p=1$ isn't every term just $0$?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent No, $n^{1-1}=1$ :)

Comment: Are you using Riemann sums? I'm not very familiar with them, maybe that's why I'm confused :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is correct.  The way of writing it, not really, when $p\neq1$.  I would compute the second limit, i.e. $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n\frac{1}{(1+r/n)^p}=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x)^p}=c_p,$$ with $c_p>0$ the constant that you have obtained, and then conclude that $\frac{1}{n^{p-1}}\frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n\frac{1}{(1+r/n)^p}$ behaves as $c_pn^{1-p}$, hence the result.

Another way of arguing (when $p\neq1$) is by bunding the terms of the sum, form bellow or from above, depending on whether $p<1$ or not.

- If $p>1$, then
  $$0 \leq \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{(n+r)^p} \leq \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{n^p} = \frac{n}{n^p} = n^{1-p},$$  hence the limit is $0$.
- If $p<1$, then
  $$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{(n+r)^p} \geq \sum_{r=1}^n\frac{1}{(n+n)^p} = \frac{n^{1-p}}{2^p},$$ so the limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: Yeah but that is what I did, no? The entire bracket is a constant term, you just went one step ahead and made a substitution $c_p$, which is of course, neater. But there is no logical/mathematical flaw in how I arrived at the result, right?

Comment: Second query: Also what is an alternative solution you would suggest? I would appreciate it if you'd elaborate your second paragraph. I'm not very experienced at writing proofs, apologies for the trouble.

Comment: I developed the argument.

Comment: Thank you, you didn't answer my first query though, of whether or not there were any flaws in my reasoning.